# Does SendGrid template engine have conditionals?

Tags: sendgrid

Sending transactional apis through SendGrid. My template (ported over from Mailchimp) has conditionals (e.g.

> `*|IF:SHOWTHISSECTION|*`

in Mailchimp syntax). This includes or excludes sections of the template based on a variable.

I can't find the analog in SendGrid, does it simply not have this capability? I'd like to suppress certain sections depending on the presence/absence of a substitution variable.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

SendGrid supports this natively now:

```
{{#if user.profile.male}}
  <p>Dear Sir</p>
{{else if user.profile.female}}
  <p>Dear Madame</p>
{{else}}
  <p> Dear Customer</p>
{{/if}}
```

Reference: https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/using-handlebars/#conditional-statements

Comment: Do you know if can do something like `{{#if count > 3}}` ?

Comment: @DauleDK: Did you find the solution for that?

Comment: Hi @HoangTrinh  - I could not make it work. I "fixed" my issue by providing more booleans like `moreThanOne` :)

Comment: @DauleDK: me too. I need to set the status color based on the status. So I "fixed" it by adding the "color" variable from Javascript, and set the color directly without using the if statement :))

Comment: you can use the `#greaterThan` block. Checkout [here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/using-handlebars/#greaterthan)

Comment: Works fine but the problem is that it adds extra space on lines where you added your conditional statements

Answer (score 6):

It's a horrible hack, but by introducing new variables and using CSS, you can hide the relevant portions of mails using `display`. So where before in Mandrill/MailChimp I'd have something like:

```
    *|IF:FAKEVAR|* 
    <p>Show some text here</p>
    *|END:IF|*
```

Instead, introduce a new variable IF_FAKEVAR, whose value is either "none" or "inherit" depending on whether FAKEVAR has a value, then do this:

```
<p style="display: *|IF_FAKEVAR|*">Show some text here</p>
```

While it's a hack, for very complex email templates, it avoids sending 70k bytes to the server for every single email, which when you have thousands or tens of thousands of mails, is prohibitive.

Comment: btw it appears you have to do style="display: *|IF_FAKEVAR|* !important;" if you really want gmail to do it...sigh.

Comment: This is really the only option unless your sections don't contain much HTML, otherwise all your HTML ends up in your application instead of the send grid template.

Answer (score 3):

SendGrid templating does not support this, but you can use a templating API like [sendwithus](https://sendwithus.com) to accomplish this on top of your SendGrid account. I believe sendwithus supports [jinja conditionals](https://www.sendwithus.com/docs/templating/), so you could do the following:

```
{% if variable %}
    <h1>{{ variable }}</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you. SendWithUs would work although that's a pricey solution and introduces yet another templating engine to my mix.. Hopefully sendgrid will get around to adding this....

Answer (score 3):

Sendgrid supports conditional using **Handlebar**

```
{{#if user.profile.male}}
  <p>Dear Sir</p>
{{else if user.profile.female}}
  <p>Dear Madame</p>
{{else}}
  <p> Dear Customer</p>
{{/if}}
```

from their documentation here https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/using-handlebars/#conditional-statements

Answer (score 3):

Below handlebars can be used in Sendgrid dynamic templates:

```
Conditional statements:
{{#if variable}}
{{#unless variable}}
{{#greaterThan variable value}}
{{#lessThan variable value}}
{{#equals variable value}}
{{#notEquals variable value}}
{{#and variable1 variable2}}
{{#or variable1 variable2}}

Looping statements:
{{#each hash}}
```

Refer https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/using-handlebars/ for detailed information

Comment: Do you know why {{#greaterThan variable value}} {{{customer_name}}} {{/greater}} dosnt work? Its like the paramters dosnt work when inside a conditional statement

Comment: Typo in the closing braces, also unless youre escaping HTML customer_name should be in double braces not triple

Comment: @Bidstrup Use {{/greaterThan}}

Comment: Does #equals have nested support?

Answer (score 2):

SendGrid doesn't have true conditionals, but it does have [Section Tags](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/section_tags.html). With those, you can define a block of text at the message level (as opposed to the distinct recipient level of a [Substitution Tag](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/substitution_tags.html)), and then call the appropriate section for the recipient as needed.

Answer (score 2):

I Know this is old, but I had the same problem and I found a solution compatible with several email managers that maybe it's helpful for someone.

You can use substitution tags with the html comment symbols value in case you want to hide a section.

```
{%OPEN_COMMENT}
<h1>Whatever section you want to hide</h1>
{%CLOSE_COMMENT}
```

Replace tags with "" respectively if you want to hide the section. Replace them with empty strings in the other case.